# rails send_file not working with iis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis

I'm trying to send .xlsx file generated by Axlsx usind send_file.

```
send_file "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/excel/test.xlsx"
```

In debug using Webrick server it works correctly, but on the production server (Windows server 2008 R2 with IIS and Helicon Zoo) it sends empty/corrupted xlsx file.

File in the path on production server is not empty.

How can I fix this?

Here is rails log

```
Started GET "/export/excel/summary_report/2" for 192.168.1.108 at 2014-02-22 22:59:57 +0000
  Processing by ExportController#export_excel_report as HTML
  Parameters: {"report_class"=>"summary_report", "entries"=>"2"}
Rendered tables/_csv_header_cell.slim (15.6ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_header_cell.slim (0.0ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_header_cell.slim (0.0ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_header_row.slim (15.6ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_header.slim (31.2ms)
Rendered tables/cells/_employee.slim (15.6ms)
Rendered tables/cells/_employee.slim (0.0ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_data_row.haml (46.8ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_data_grid.slim (62.4ms)
Rendered tables/_csv_table.slim (156.0ms)
Rendered filters/_summary_report.haml (171.6ms)
Sent file public/excel/summary_report1393109998_178.xlsx (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 312ms
```

Comment: Have you checked your log file to see what happens when the file is sent?

Comment: Added log to post. "Sent 0.0ms" looks questionably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you rendering the Axlsx to a file, and then trying to send that? If so, you might have better luck with:

```
xlsx_package = Axlsx::Package.new(...)
# do whatever
send_data xlsx_package.to_stream.read
```

That should at least take care of any file permissions / path issues.

You can also use a gem like [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails), which I wrote, to create and send xlsx files. I have not, however, tested it on Windows IIS.

Comment: Yes, I used to render Axlsx to file. Your solution worked for me. Thank you very much.